# How to index 3d array (t, x, y) using another 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array of values,

```
vals = np.array([
    [
        [10, 20, 30],
        [40, 50, 60],
    ],
    [
        [15, 25, 35],
        [45, 55, 65],
    ],
])
```

and a corresponding 3d array of coordinates

```
coords = np.array([
    [
        [0,1],
        [0,2],
        [1,1]
    ],
    [
        [0,0],
        [1,1],
        [1,2]
    ]
])
```

Each inner-most array of `coords` represents (x,y) coordinates corresponding to one of the 2d arrays within vals. For example, the coordinate `[0,1]` in `coords` corresponds to the value 20 and the coordinate `[1,2]` in `coords` corresponds to the value 65.

How do I use `coords` to subset `vals` in this manner?

I can solve this specific example like so

```
np.array([
    vals[0][coords[0][:, 0], coords[0][:, 1]],
    vals[1][coords[1][:, 0], coords[1][:, 1]]
])

array([[20, 30, 50],
       [15, 55, 65]])
```

but obviously I'd like a more dynamic solution.

Comment: Advanced indexing: [`vals[np.arange(len(coords))[:,None], coords[..., 0], coords[..., 1]]`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/4e2803c6.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny how writing my questions always seems to lead me to an answer.. Staring at the answer matrix,

```
array([[20, 30, 50],
       [15, 55, 65]])
```

I asked myself, "how would I reproduce this matrix from raw index values?". For example, to extract the value 20, I know I can do

```
vals[0, 0, 1]
```

If I wanted to extract the first row of values in the answer, `[20, 30, 50]` I should do

```
vals[[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,2,1]]
```

Then to get the full answer matrix, I should do

```
vals[[[0,0,0],[1,1,1]], [[0,0,1],[0,1,1]], [[1,2,1],[0,1,2]]]
```

From here, I set my focus on producing those three index matrices. They can be constructed as follows:

```
i1 = np.arange(coords.shape[0])[:, None].repeat(coords.shape[1], axis=1)
i2 = coords[:,:,0]
i3 = coords[:,:,1]

# Thus the generalized solution
vals[i1, i2, i3]
```

This answer is extremely similar to the advanced indexing solution mentioned by @Psidom in the comments, but perhaps less elegant.